# Как убрать зависимость ширины верхнего элемента от нижнего

Tags: activity, android

Есть такой прекрасный замечательный и восхитительный элемент(:
[image]

Под ним спрятан вот такой элемент с помощью *setVisibility(View.GONE)*:
[image]

Когда я делю нижний элемент видимым (*setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)*), то у верхнего элемента увеличивается картинка, и получается такая картина (ширина картинки подстраивается под ширину нижнего элемента): 
[image]

А теперь **вопрос**: как сделать так, чтобы при показывании нижнего элемента ширина не менялась?

p.s. структура:

[image]

Comment: Самый простой выход- отказаться от размещения внутри одной таблицы на разных строках.

Comment: это вовсе и не странно. В таблице по определению ячейки во всей колонке имеют одинаковую ширину. Используйте , как ответил @JustixLoL, обычные леяуты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Серьёзно , убери вообще таблицу , сделай обычными лаяутами....)